# python tensorflow running has warning keep_dims is deprecated, use keepdims instead and error bash: line 1: 28101 Killed

Tags: python

when I run python file I have  warning   keep_dims is deprecated get a error bash: line 1: 28101 Killed  program is killd .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means that keep_dims is henceforth not supported by whichever library you are using. It could be true in older versions, but now onwards use keepdims instead of keep_dims in your code. You may read about it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6815). Actually keepdims does not follow PEP-8's naming convention, so there is kind off controversy between these two.

Comment: Why do you say it does not follow PEP8?

Comment: From PEP8: "Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability". Underscore separation is not obligatory

Comment: keepdims, basically means keep dimensions, so its made from 2 different words. Hence should be separated by underscores

Comment: It could be good to separate words, but it does not violate PEP8 not to do so. Look at some names in the standard library: `namedtuple` or `frozenset`. It is ok.

Comment: But problem must be something else, as keepdims isn't discarded, its keep_dims which is removed.